# Unable to run a command in the background using subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I have a piped command that I am running using the `subprocess.call` function. It looks somewhat like this:

```
cmd = 'echo password | ./create_apps.sh 4 &'
```

The `create_apps.sh` script, is launching a bunch of python3 apps with the '&' command as well, apart from doing some other stuff. Something similar to running multiple commands like these in a loop in the bash script:

```
echo password | sudo python3 app.py &
```

The issue I am having is that the `subprocess` command never returns, i.e the control flow is never switched back to the main program. Could anyone help with this? I just need this command to run in the background while my main flow of the program continues as normal. I've tried using `Popen` using something like this (as suggested in some of the other answers):

```
 p1 = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'password'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['./create_apps.sh', '4'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
```

but that is showing a similar behavior. Could anyone help?